# simple root of a complex variable function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have encountered the following question:

Let $f_{\epsilon}(z)=\sin(z)+\epsilon e^z$. Prove that $f_{\epsilon}(z)$ has a simple root $z_{\epsilon}$ with the property that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \,\,\,z_{\epsilon}=\pi$. I try to apply the Rouche's theorem to the functions $g(z)=\sin(z)$ and $\,\,f_{\epsilon}$ but I couldnt prove that the absolute value of $sinz$ is bigger than a positive number on a circle centered at $\pi$ and I also don't understand how the limit goes to $\pi$ not to any other roots of sin. Any help would be great!

Comment: You can just let $\epsilon\to 0$, and verify that $\pi$ is indeed a simple root.

Comment: But why it goes to $\pi$ and not any other simple roots of sin?

Comment: The implicit function theorem can be used to guarantee such a root.  There is one for every root of $\sin z$, not just $\pi$.

Comment: Could you explain more, how can I apply the theorem, please. thank you very much.